# Выполнить код только в одном из worker'ов при запуске через gunicorn

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing, gunicorn

Имеется flask-приложение запускающееся через gunicorn в несколько worker'ов. Нужно запустить фоновый поток только в одном экзепляре. Что-то аналогичное такому запуску:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
event = threading.Event()
thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(event,))
thread.setDaemon(True)

def app_run():
    thread.start()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, threaded=True)
    event.set()
    thread.join()
```